# Check remote profile size

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to get correct numbers while checking size of user profiles.

While executing this code remotely, I get wrong numbers.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $credentials
-ScriptBlock {

$colItems = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer
-eq $true} | Sort-Object foreach ($i in $colItems) {
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force -ErrorAction Ignore | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB" }

}
```

This gives me numbers like: `C:\Users\admin -- 673.42 MB` but when I run the same code locally it says `47.9 MB` which is the true value.

Can anyone give me a tip or explain why is that. Thanks

$Server has the server name which I am passing earlier in the script. Everything works except the correct output from the code above.

Comment: It depends on what you are holding in $server. what exactly you are passing in $server in both the cases?

Comment: your path needs to be pointing to the right thing

Comment: Edited the main post. My point is to get the correct values of profile sizes saved in C:\Users\. When I run the same code locally, it gives me correct values, but invoking or using PSsession gives me wrong results and I had no luck trying to google why.